# Issue with google sheets API quickstart (v4)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm trying to go through the following tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs#

And when I get to the step to run the quick start file
node quickstart.js I get the following error message:
Olivers-MacBook-Pro:incrementum oliverpike$ node quickstart.js

```
undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /Volumes/github-image/bitcoin-core/quickstart.js:43:39
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
```

quickstart.js is trying to read from ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json but that file is empty which is resulting in the unexpected end of JSON input error.

How do I determine what needs to go in that file?

Comment: Remove the file there is an else condition in the code.

Comment: Thanks - deleting the file and rerunning did the job. If you put your comment as a response I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the file and the code will trigger an `else` condition to get authentication.